# sanity check file to produce binary answer

Tags: unix, regex, grep, sed, awk

What Unix command(s) can I use to determine the existence of each of several words and the non-existence of each of several words which will produce a binary answer?

For example: I want to be sure that a file has the word "foo" listed 6 times and "bar" listed 8 times. I also want to be sure that the file has neither "fizz" nor any "buzz"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegent ways to do this, but this will do the trick, for a file called `test`:

```
if [ `grep -c bar test` == 8 ] && [ `grep -c foo test` == 6 ] && [ `grep -c fizz test` == 0 ] && [ `grep -c buzz test` == 0 ] ; then  echo "yes" ; else echo "no" ; fi
```

Comment: This will fail when words appear multiple times on the same rows, since `grep -c` only returns number of matching _rows_, not word counts. `echo "test test" | grep -c test` will return 1.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Good point Ocasta, can you add more information about the data structure to your question?

Comment: @Paul, I'm trying to build a sanity check for a derived text file. It may be that the same word appears multiple times on each line but if my understanding of how this particular text file is built is correct then it is a safe bet that the file is sane if each of the words are mentioned at least once.

Comment: So I guess a more relevant question would be how do I get a binary response if foo and bar exist an unknown number of times (i just want to be sure they are in the file)?

Comment: Changing the if to `if [ grep -c bar test -gt 0 ] && [ grep -c foo test` -gt 0 ]` would probably do it...